# How to count the number of a times a program is 'run' in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am working on a plugin that requires to take the number of times a program in the active editor window is run/compiled in Eclipse. Would checking the number of times the *.class* is modified solve my problem?

Comment: No. The class could be modified several times without running and vice versa...

Comment: Thanks @Zephyr, then how do I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm afraid StackOverflow is not a site where we write your code for you, but we aim to solve specific coding problems.

Answer (score 1):

You asked about running *and* compiling; the number of times the .class file changes would roughly indicate the number of times it was *compiled* by Eclipse, but as mentioned earlier, has no relation to the number of times it was executed.

If the class/project is executed with Eclipse using the run/debug launches, your plugin could listen for launches using the [ILaunchListener](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2FILaunchListener.html) interface, take a look at the other interfaces in the [debug package](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fdebug%2Fcore%2Fpackage-summary.html) too.